Clarification on Criminal record question in job seeker visa application to Germany
I’m applying to Germany for a job seeker visa.
A Domestic assault case was filed against me in the US in 2018. I was arrested for 12 hours, then the case final disposition was dismissed and expunged (dismissed after attending anger management classes).
Should I answer yes or no for criminal record in the visa application?

What is the actual wording (in the visa application) of the question about which you are asking?

@DavidRecallsMonica *Do you have a criminal record? Yes or No is the question asked in "opportunity card" application form and I lived in US for 6 years and incident happend in  2018. I am a indian national and currntly live in India

I belive this question belongs on Expatriates, not Travel.

Which state? Laws vary by state, some may still maintain a public or confidential record of the charge and its disposition even after expungement. Some states remove all records of an arrest and/or subsequent court case from the public record, and the individual may legally deny or fail to acknowledge ever having been arrested for or charged with any crime which has been expunged

Isn't the question “Sind Sie vorbestraft? Have you ever been convicted?”

On what a 'criminal record' is (and may contain) will depend on the country you are appling to. In Germany, a criminal record will not contain anything that a (final decision of a) judge has found you guilty of and where you have been sentenced to a punishment that is less than 3 months. Should you add this information to your application, assume that a German consulate official will come to the conclusion that your situation would not lead to an entry into a German criminal record.

Answering 'Yes' will not lead automatically to a refusal, but will be judged based on the given circumstances.

@DavidRecallsMonica it is in TN in 2018

@Relaxed No the question is * Do you have a criminal record? here is the form https://videx.diplo.de/videx/visum-erfassung/videx-langfristiger-aufenthalt

@MarkJohnson I already faced refusal answering Yes for US. But their application form is very specific , even dismissal  should be mentioned. I want to be very cautious with German visa

Remember that a German consulate official in the US will know that things work differently in the US than Germany.

@MarkJohnson  answering 'NO' is safe?

As meantioned in my first comment, 'Yes' with  the given circumstances ('was arrested for 12 hours, then the case final disposition was dismissed and expunged (dismissed after attending anger management classes)') should lead to the conclusion that it is not a conviction under German law. Just because the US may, possibly, consider you a convicted felon, doesn't mean that Germany will do the same. My understanding of US law, only a jury (or when none is required - a judge) may actually convict someone of breaking the law.

From what you wrote, no court was involved - and thus, for Germany, no conviction exists.

@coco Are you running this page through some sort of automated translator? I followed your link and I do see “Sind Sie vorbestraft?” You can clearly answer “no” to that question.

@Relaxed There is a dropdown for language selection at the top on the page (on my mobile). When I switch to English, I get the wording "Have you ever been convicted?"

In UK, taking a voluntary correction course (such as when caught speeding) is an alternative to receiving a conviction. That's the point – no conviction – not a criminal. In my example you don't have to inform the insurance company.

@MarkJohnson I did go to court, I came out on Bail after 12hours and I got a slip with date to attend court and I hired a lawyer and in the court he spoke to police and said this kind of case will have up to one year jail and the judge is willing to dismiss the case if you take anger management classes. I took that option to go to anger management classes and after completing classes I got another court date where they checked the book and dismissed the case and expunged it after before a year.

@Relaxed Thankyou for the advice. I have elaborated on how it got dismissed. Could you go through the comment and see if the answer is  still 'no'? and yes, I am using the automatic Google translate. Once of my friend who is already in Germany shared his screen the other day. I see the same "Have you ever been convicted" ? but mine in India while I open the same form it shows "do you have a criminal record"?

@WeatherVane yes according to US I am not convicted, when I am in US I have always answered no for job applications, loans and insurances. It's just the immigration thing I am in doubt cause they say they do lot of bkground checks and share data between countries. while my case has been expunged and a conviction according to US, I have no idea how this is considered according to Germany.

@coco I don't see how this makes a difference, dismissed is dismissed, you have not been convicted to any specific sentence but ultimately you'll have to decide for yourself. I would be very surprised if such data is shared between the US and Germany.
